# KO (knockoutjs) data binding issue with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js, model-binding

I've a strange problem which is specific to IE (I've checked multiple versions starting with IE8, 9 & 10), **my model records are multiplied** *(i.e. if I've 2 records, it displays 2X2 = 4, if 3 then 3X3 = 9)*. I've a simple Grid which binds with my viewModel which I fetch via getJson after loading the page. Here's the code snippet (thre's more I've just kept the minimal) -

```
function createCommentsKO(){
    $.getJSON('http://www.tempSite.com/getMyjson',
        function (data) {
            ...
            viewModelComments.allComments = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.AllComments);
            ...
            ko.applyBindings(viewModelComments, document.getElementById("divComments"));
    });
```

In the Grid, I iterate witnin  like -

```
<div id="divComments">
...
<table>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: allComments">
    <tr data-bind="attr:{className:_Deleted()?'deletedTR':'deletedTR_NO'}">
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
        <span data-bind='text:Comment'></span>
        ...
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
...
</div>
```

How is this possible? why does IE multiply my model records, it renders perfectly in Firefox. Any clue?

---

Some more info - 
Here viewModelComments.allComments is an Observable array bound to the grid. My json result returned is a JSON object with an array and some other objects.
I separated the implementation for a small part and tried the following which showed proper result -

```
 viewModelComments.allComments(data.AllComments);
```

how does it differ from the following: (BTW, I need each element in the array of object to be observable for further use)

```
 viewModelComments.allComments = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.AllComments);
```

Comment: Can you post more of your HTML?  Are you closing all of the tags (like the `tr` above?

Comment: You are missing the closing `</tr>`.  Is it in your real html?

Comment: sorry about the silly mistake .. my code is well formed. Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to view it correctly Firefox. It has to be something else. I've verified that the html is well formed.

Comment: From the data you've posted no one can tell what's wrong. Maybe put some more HTML and JSON object you're receiving as well.

Comment: Understood. I've updated the post. I've multiple tabs but as I'm binding with specific UI element bindings are isolated. I tried to disable all other bindings but still it shows replicated Grid where as the underlying array has correct number of elements. If I add a new element in array - it shows two in Grid!

Comment: I've got some clues which indicate that IE is calling my "$(document).ready" twice! I render this comments section dynamically after the page is loaded. Probably the "createCommentsKO" is being called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it came out that my $().ready which created and applied KO bindings was triggered twice in case of IE. I was loading some partial content dynamically. The dynamically loaded page had a $().ready to load KO - this was called twice by IE. So, instead of $().ready I transformed it into a callDocReady function and invoked it manually after loading the content dynamically - this ensured that its invoked only once.

Sorry I thot it'd be a KO issue. One more thing I've found is that if any controls being bound to KO and are also required to be integrated with a jQuery plugin like jquery.numeric.js or jqueryui autocomplete  then this has to be performed after KO binding - if its done before it then those integration will be overridden (in short not work)

Hope it helps